# The most common names by year in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a csv excel file with names (JMÉNO), year and I need to write a function `names_chart (year, filename, n)` which will write count of the most common names (n) of the year (according to data from a file). I already wrote a code which will write the most common names but without YEAR parameter.
Could somebody help me with this problem?

part of the csv file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf86c7305859b2fbc79b043a5965ddfe

code:

```
import re

def process_word(word, words):
    if len(word) < 4:
        return
    w = word.lower()
    if w in words:
        words[w] += 1
    else:
        words[w] = 1

def get_words(text):
    words = {}
    for w in re.findall("\w+", text):
        process_word(w, words)
    return words


def read_in(filename):
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return f.read()    

def print_top(words, count):
    sorted_names = sorted(words, key=words.get, reverse=True)
    for w in sorted_names[:count]:
        print(w, words[w])

def names_chart(year, filename, n):
    text = read_in(filename)
    words = get_words(text)
    print_top(words, n)


names_chart(1987, "du06_jmena.csv", 10)
```

Comment: Why not have a dictionary of dictionaries, with one dictionary for each year? The main loop would need to decide (based on the year parameter) which dictionary to record the given name in (and spawn a new dictionary if that year hasn't yet appeared). Since this seems to be homework, I'll leave the details for you.

Comment: Can you post just a **part** of the actual CSV here? Maybe a few rows?

Comment: This can also be done simply with [pandas](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/10min.html), which can read files into a dataframe and do all kinds of things such as find the most frequent values `df['item'].value_counts().idxmax()`.  Provide a gist of the dataset, and someone will likely assist you.

Comment: Thank you for answers. To John Coleman: I am not sure in which funcition I should do it. Could you give me a hint? To not_a_robot: It's only one column with name COMMA year COMMA year.... Exactly like in the attached screenshot. To pylang: I believe, that there is easier way to do it without any other library (?).

Comment: Are you on github?  You can post a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/) of your dataset.  Give some data, and it can be demonstrated how easy it is with pandas.

Comment: Do you mean a text in csv file? Sure, I can a few rows. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf86c7305859b2fbc79b043a5965ddfe

Comment: @Longjing Please add some lines of the CSV file to your question, so that people don't have to digg through the comments...

Comment: To Roland Smith: Ok, It's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also use pandas for this, but in a different way.

I would write my function like this:

```
def common_names(year, filename, N):
    yearcol = str(year)
    namecol = 'JMÉNO'
    df = (
        pandas.read_csv(filename)
            .sort_values(by=[yearcol], ascending=False)
            .head(N)
    )[[namecol, yearcol]]
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) is a prominent library for data analysis.  Using DataFrames, we can simplify your analysis to a single function.  Since no output type was specified, we will return a list of name, value pairs:

```
import pandas as pd

def names_chart (year, filename, n, get_df=False):
    """Return the n most common names of a given year as a list of tuples."""
    # Input processing
    if isinstance(year, int):
        year = str(year)
    names = "JMÉNO"

    # pandas: find indices in `df` that are most common names/year (condition)
    # Return only the names and given year columns
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",", encoding='latin1')
    condition = df[year].nlargest(n).index
    top_names_per_year = df.loc[condition, [names, year]]

    # Output processing
    if get_df:
        return top_names_per_year

    return top_names_per_year.values.tolist()
```

You can now access the data as a `list`:

```
names_chart (2011, "./@data/gistfile1.txt", 3)

# Output (List, default):
[['AARON', 4], ['AARIAN KAMER', 1], ['A-MI', 0]]
```

You can optionally return the `top_names_per_year` DataFrame object with `get_df=True`.  DataFrames have many more [powerful features](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/12-pandas-techniques-python-data-manipulation/).

```
df = names_chart (2011, "./@data/gistfile1.txt", 3, get_df=True)
print(type(df))
df

# Output (DataFrame):
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

           JMÉNO  2011
11         AARON     4
10  AARIAN KAMER     1
0           A-MI     0
```

The resulting subset showing indices, a column of names and corresponding largest frequencies in the `year` column.

Comment: I think you could simply your non-dataframe return statement with `df2.values.tolist()`. It'll be a list of lists, not a list of tuples, though.

Comment: Great advice.  Thanks @Paul H.